# How to instantly display a custom page in nginx when upstream web server is down?

Tags: nginx, webserver

I tried to do this but for some reason it does work as expected:

```
server {
...
location / {
    if (!-f /opt/jira/work/catalina.pid) {
       return 503;
    }
proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

It seems that the file test doesn't work because it will return 503 even if the file exists on disk.

I want to be able to display an error page when the upstream webserver is not responding but without waiting for this too much. It should respond instantly if there is nothing running on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the file does not accessible to nginx worker. You should check permissions.